# Выполнение php скрипта с планировщик задач на windows

Tags: php, windows, cron, планировщик-задач

Как вызывать php скрипт на удаленном сервере каждый час в планировщике задач? Как в cron, нужно чтобы каждый час автоматически планировщик задач заходил на url, по которому находится php, выполняющий саму задачу.

Мне нужно чтобы каждый час планировщик задач запрашивал этот url. Возможно ли вообще это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел следующее [решение](http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/7084).

Сначала надо написать скрипт, который будет отправлять http запрос. Вот он весь ниже написан на jscript (реализация javascript от Microsoft).

```
var request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); 
var url = "http://localhost/cronScript.php";
request.open("GET", url);
request.send(null);
WScript.Sleep(500); // чтобы скрипт не завершился, прежде чем запрос уйдет в сеть
WScript.echo("Done!!!");
```

Последнюю строку можно, убрать - она просто выводит сообщение (надо просто убедиться, что он отрабатывает). Весь этот код сохраните в файл c расширением .js например cronScript.js.

Теперь надо создать задачу в планировщике Windows. Для этого нажмите Win+R -> Выполнить taskschd.msc ([подробнее о работе с планировщиком](http://www.wseven.info/task/))

1. В расположенном справа меню Действия нажмите Создать задачу (или
   Создать простую задачу).
2. В окне "Создание задачи" введите название новой задачи и ее описание
3. Переключитесь на вкладку "Триггеры", нажмите кнопку "Создать" и назначьте дату, время и частоту выполнения задачи.
4. Теперь в разделе "Действия" создайте новый пункт "запуск программы" и укажите путь к нашему cronScript.js.

Это все. Теперь если по адресу localhost/cronScript.php (а именно сюда указывает наш скрипт) поместить следующий php код

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen("cronLog.txt", "a");
    $str = "Last timestamp: ".date("H:i:s")."\n";
    fwrite($handle, $str);
    fclose($handle);
```

То в файл cronLog.txt будет записываться метка через определенный интервал времени.

Comment: Не знаю что и сказать, спс тебе большое.

Comment: @Leno пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Тут есть необходимая информация https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/01ef940c-0d05-4fa3-8439-359ee216c9ef/-http-?forum=iisru

> Если скрипт не интерактивный (не требует взаимодействия с
>   пользователем), то задача сводится к простой загрузке содержимого с
>   вэб сервера. Это можно сделать какой-нибудь утилитой или скриптом.
>
> Например, `wget http://mysite.ru/script.php`
>
> Или Powershell скрипт:
>
> `$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient $client.DownloadDada(
>   "http://mysite.ru/script.php" )`